# "Have you got familiar with new working environment?" Which tense should I use in this sentence?

Tags: tenses

I have been confused by the use of some tenses. Especially when I have to use a state verb.

In the sentence above, can I use  the simple present or past tense? Like:

- Do you get familiar with new working environment?
- Did you get familiar with new working environment?

Does it have the same meaning?

Comment: "Have you become familiar ..." is far more idiomatic.

Comment: "Have you familiarised yourself ...?" is perhaps even more idiomatic.

Comment: If you want to talk about the present, you should say *Are you getting familiar with your new working environment?* The verb *get* in *get familiar* is not a state verb.

Comment: I suggest that SE English Language Learners may be a more suitable place for questions of this sort, especially as you appear to have difficulties using articles.

Answer (score 1):

You mention "state verbs", so it seems you think that *get* is a stative verb. It's not.

We use the simple present for stative verbs, and tend to use the continuous present for dynamic verbs (unless we're talking about a habitual action).
So if you want to talk about the present, you should say:

> I am getting familiar with the new working environment,

unless it's a habitual action.

Is getting familiar a habitual action? It could be. The sentence would be fine in the context:

> Whenever I get a new assignment, there are several things I do. I get acquainted with my coworkers. I get familiar with the new working environment.

But generally, people don't change working environments habitually, so it's not usually a habitual action, so you should usually use the continuous present for *get familiar* and *get acquainted.*

Answer (score 0):

"Did you get familiar with your new working environment?" and "Have you gotten familiar with your new working environment?" would both be correct, and would mean roughly the same thing, though I would feel that "Have you gotten" would be a bit more formal or demanding than "did you get".

Comment: Actually, *gotten* does not work in the UK.

Comment: @David Indeed! "Gotten" only works in the US.

Comment: @WS2 Sorry. Typo. How many times does one write the exact opposite of what one intends. (Very British use of “one”. ) Have deleted.

Comment: Apparently it was the original usage of the word that lapsed into disuse in the UK until America brought it back. https://stroppyeditor.wordpress.com/2017/03/27/the-us-has-gotten-this-word-back-and-the-uk-probably-will-too/

Answer (score 0):

As nick012000 has rightly put it, all of them are correct.

The difference between them, however, rely on the context the sentence is describing.

1. Do you get familiar with new working environments [*sic*]?

This question is aimed at knowing whether the recipient **usually** gets familiar with new working environments. That is, if getting familiar with new working environments is something normal/natural/habitual to him. It's like a of the recipient.

2. Did you get familiar with the [*sic*] new working environment?

This second question relates to a specific point in time. Differently from the other question, which doesn't have any space and time context, this specifically asks for whether the recipient got or didn't get familiar with the new working environment.

3. Have you gotten familiar with the new working environment?

Finally, this last question asks about an ongoing problem the recipient is having, and whether they have improved on getting familiar with the new working environment. As nick012000 stated above, this looks a bit more formal, but I would add that not too much. It's the appropriate way to ask about any developments of ongoing concerns/processes.

p.s.: I've made two [*sic*] notes. The first because environment in that question should be in the plural form, because the question is general, regarding all environments, not one in particular. The second because the question revolves around a specific working environment, which requires an article.

Comment: As Andrew Leach posted in nick012000's comment, *gotten* is the (American English version) of the "to get" past participle.

Comment: Maybe you'll find this link useful: http://bit.ly/2IYCKkZ